# After invalidate(), is it possible to get a new session from the request object?

Tags: session, servlets, invalidation

After invalidation of a session, is it possible to get new session through request object  via request.getSession() without making a new request?

My request object flow to 1st page to 2nd page and 2nd page to 1st page again 1st page to 2nd page and again same 2nd page to 2nd page ....request page can not be change but every time request 1st page to 2nd page we need to fetch detail to session and invalidate it and again created it.. 
like this

```
HttpSession session = request.getsession(false)
String user = (String)session.getAttribute("name");
session.invalidate();
session=request.getSession(true);
RequestDispacher dis = request.requestDispatcher("path");
dis.forword(request,respone);
```

but this not work on 2nd time
it gives to null session or details

also try to set session id in coming cookies
like this

```
Cookie[] c = request.getCookies();
            for(Cookie k: c){
                if(k.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("JSESSIONID")){
                    System.out.println("k.getValue() : "+k.getValue());
                    System.out.println("httpSession.getId() : "+httpSession.getId());
                    k.setValue(httpSession.getId());
                }
            }
```

Comment: Why are you invalidating the session if you need it?

Comment: for security  purpose

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As-per the [Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getSession%28%29), just call `request.getSession()`:

> Returns the current HttpSession associated with this request or, if there is no current session and create is true, returns a new session.
>
> If create is false and the request has no valid HttpSession, this
>   method returns null.
>
> To make sure the session is properly maintained, you must call this
>   method before the response is committed. If the container is using
>   cookies to maintain session integrity and is asked to create a new
>   session when the response is committed, an IllegalStateException is
>   thrown.

So calling the `getSession` method will create you a new session:

```
final HttpSession session = request.getSession()
```

Here's an example JSP that proves the code works:

**test.jsp**

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Session invalidation test</title>
</head>
<body>
<% 

// Uses implicit session for JSP

out.println("Session is " + session);
session.invalidate();
out.println("\nNew session is " + request.getSession());

request.getRequestDispatcher("/test2.jsp").forward(request, response);

%>
</body>
</html>
```

**test2.jsp**

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Session invalidation test</title>
</head>
<body>
<% 

out.println("Session is " + request.getSession());

%>
<h1>Test 2</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

When executed on Tomcat6, the output in my browser is:

```
Session is org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade@9317bfb
Test 2
```

which indicates `test.jsp` was exectued and successfully forwarded to test2.jsp.

Comment: You can also just use `request.getSession()` without the boolean argument.

Comment: i agree your ans but my question is after this
out.println("Session is " + session);
session.invalidate();
out.println("New session is " + request.getSession());
and call request dispatcher and forword to another path
and call session 
request.getSession 
so ican'd get it
it gives null
but i needed in my project
for maintain session and also sequire my session to no one heck it

Comment: I think you need to seriously evaluate your requirements and truly understand what security means, how you achieve it with Java EE and perhaps consult someone who's an expert in secure web applications. Look at OWASP and understand that first.

Comment: See my updated answer; I've extended my test to prove to you what works.

Answer (score 0):

After the `invalidate()`

you should write

[`req.getSession(true)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getSession%28boolean%29)

Then `getSession()` method will check whether already a session is existing or not. If a `session` is existing, it will `return` that session object, otherwise a new session creates and returns to client.

otherwise  if you try to do something like

```
session.inValidate();
session..trySomething()  //leads to exception "Session already invalidated."
```

Comment: i try this but next time we get session object on same request object..it gives null ....

Comment: +1 for explaining how exception is thrown by attempting to call method on invalidated session. Thanks.